# comparison of two images

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a binarized image to which i add noise and then try to filter out the noise using various thresholding algorithms such as otsu and niblack.How can i compare the resultant image with the original image so as to find the percentage error that exists between the two??

the original image is as such:
[image: original]

and the resultant image is:
[image: result]

I need a way to find the percentage error that is present.

Note:original and resultant image are of the same size.

Answer (score 4):

> I need a way to find the percentage error that is present.

You can find percentage error in multiple different ways, and you will get multiple different answers. Different measures emphasize different aspects of similarity. There's no single "right" method.

Some common measures of [image similarity](http://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/doxygen/ImageSimilarityMetricsPage.html) include:

- [Cross-correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation)
- [Mean squared difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error)
- [Mutual information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information)

Generally the simplest methods, such as mean squared difference, don't agree very well with human perception. Your starting point is good though: if the images are exactly the same size, and are binary, then you've already excluded a couple of fundamental challenges of comparing images (orientation, scaling, brightness/contrast variations).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest error measures in use are RMSE, MAE, (P)SNR.

- RMSE -- root mean square error. `sqrt(mean((I1(:) - I2(:))^2))`
- MAE -- maximum absolute error. `max(abs(I1(:) - I2(:)))`
- PSNR -- Peak Signal to Noise ratio: `10*log10(1/mean((I1(:) - I2(:)).^2));`

Find more information about them in the literature!

Comment: do the images need to be converted into any particular class such as double or uint8 for the above statements to be used?? i get an error on trying to implement them.

Comment: obviously there is some floating point involved, so you should have them as double. And I did not test the code, I just wrote it down. I just spotted a bracket inbalance.